# Domain Transfer DNS Glue Records Timing / Downtime

Tags: dns-hosting, domain-registrar, glue-record

I'm transferring a domain I manage from a registrar who does not allow me to use third party DNS. I've inherited this issue and am trying to minimize downtime as I have mail and a website running on this domain. I've already got DNS setup at the receiving registrar and none of the DNS entries will change besides the GLUE record obviously. I'm also obviously not as familiar with this process as I should be. The domain is a .com

I transferred another domain as a test which took five full days to become available in the new registrar. They say it will take 5-7 for the transfer to complete which is a long time to have email down. The domain I tested with is a .org

My questions are:

- Is there anything else I can do to minimize downtime?
- How long does it take for glue record to update? Does this happen right away, or does it happen at the end of the 5-7 day period? is there a period where the glue records wouldn't point at anything?
- I contacted the outgoing registrar and they're refusing to work with me. They refuse to change the Glue Records to point at my new DNS and they also refuse to expedite the transfer. Is there any way to compel them to do either one of those things?
- Is there any way to lodge a complaint with ICANN over this?

I appreciate everyone's time and input.

Comment: This is really dependent per registar I think, I worked for a managed service provider here in the Netherlands where we could complete it in a day. But 5 days is extremely long in this day and age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really dependent per registar I think, I worked for a managed service provider here in the Netherlands where we could complete it in a day. But 5 days is extremely long in this day and age. Most of the service providers need to interact with APIs of the registrar and it might be that they do a bulk update of multiple customers every 5 days. But that's something only they know and is in their software.

If you have an account manager or a customer success manager I would definitely talk with that person if they can speed up the process. I would ask check if you have an SLA and if that matches they time they take, if not you might be able to file a claim.

---

Edit

The 5 days look like to be an ICANN policy
*The Registry Operator shall complete the requested transfer unless, within five (5) calendar days*

https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/transfer-policy-2016-06-01-en

Comment: I'm not sure which domain extension and which registrar so it might be very different

Comment: It's WIX --> Namecheap and .com

Comment: See my edit, ICANN policy

Answer (score 1):

I've performed many Registrar transfers of .com domains and the process generally does take upwards of 5 days but sometimes is completed sooner than that.

The transfer request will be completed within 5 days but that doesn't mean your DNS zone and records will be unavailable during that period of time, they will be available via the original Registrar and DNS hoster until such time that the transfer actually completes.